# CUDA or same something that can be available to intel graphic card?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I want to learn GPGPU and CUDA programming. But I know that only Nvidia card support it. My laptop has an Intel HD Graphic Card. So I need to search if it is possible to do GPGPU or something like that with Intel graphic card. Thanks for any information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 6):

To develop in CUDA your options are:

- Use an NVIDIA GPU - all NVIDIA server, desktop and laptop GPUs support CUDA since around 2006, since your laptop does not have one you could try using one remotely.
- Use [PGI CUDA x86](http://www.pgroup.com/resources/cuda-x86.htm), not free but does what you want.
- Use [gpuocelot](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/) to execute the PTX on the CPU, that's an open-source project in development so YMMV.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do GPGPU on Intel HD Graphics cards today, unless you do shader-based programming (which was common practice in the days before CUDA and OpenCL).

In my experience, the PGI X86 stuff seems to have fallen flat and I'm not aware of anyone using that.  Ocelot is another attempt at the same, but it is very reasearchy and not fully robust at this point.

The only OpenCL compliant devices from Intel are the latest CPUs (Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge).

What CPU do you have in your system?

Comment: My CPU is a Intel Core i5-2520M. I don't know if it is Sandy Bridge or Ivy Bridge. However, I thought OpenCL does not requires it? How about Larrate and ArBB? There are many kinds of this work, and not all of them can stand in the future.

Answer (score 1):

CUDA is Nvidia specific as starter. The GPU emulators are always there in CUDA, so you can use them without a graphics card easily, though it will be slow. A faster solution is the 
the [x86 implementation](http://blogs.nvidia.com/2011/06/cuda-now-available-for-multiple-x86-processors/). Any of these will allow you to learn the basics of CUDA without using the GPU at all.

If you are want to learn GPGPU in general you still have the option to learn OpenCL, which more widely supported, including AMD, Intel, Nvidia etc... E.g. Intel has an OpenCL SDK (the target is the CPU then, but I guess is irrelevant for you).

After learning the basics of either CUDA or OpenCL, the other will be easy to learn. Neither the syntax nor the semantics are the same, but it is easy step forward as the concepts are the same.

Comment: openCL doesn't run on (current) Intel GPUs. Their implementation only runs on the CPU - ok for learning but not really for applications

Comment: The GPU emulator you're most likely referring to has not been a part of CUDA anymore for the last couple of versions.

Comment: Thanks, you give me some clues. I intent to play with OpenCL. Cause I want to see any high performance o parallel processing, not just the programming. I have heard about ArBB but OpenCL is for heterogenous, right?

Comment: I haven't touched CUDA for a while now, I didn't know that the emulators have been removed. I think ArBB is similar to Nvidia libraries like Cublas. They both run on the target hardware, but hiding the complexity of the architecture, with having simple C/C++ libs. I think for learning it is basically irrelevant whether the actual target is CPU or GPU.